# How can I search for emails containing embedded images in the Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

Searching for `body:png` only returns emails containing embedded PNG images. Is there way to search for any image format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to search for any image format. One possible workaround is from [juzzle](https://www.reddit.com/user/juzzle) on  [reddit](https://redd.it/mz6kvx):

> the only practical method is to search for messages with Not Has Attachments and filter by size - emails with embedded images will typically be larger than 100 kB - less than that will only find emails with embedded signature/footer images.

which would be `size:large hasattachment:false` according to https://lookeen.com/blog/tips-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-using-the-most-important-search-commands.

Answer (score 2):

I would try `body:(png OR jpg)`; or, `(body:png OR body:jpg)`